Slot on bottom of FTM-6000?
The Yaesu FTM-6000 has a large slot in the bottom of the unit:

Is that for a specific purpose, like for some sort of mounting option or something? Or is that where air gets pulled into the unit when the fan is running?

Perhaps pop those screws out and a take a pic of the internals?
